# Генерация строки для шрифта штрихкода Code 128

Tags: python, строки, barcode

Столкнулся с задачей по генерации штрихкода по стандарту Code 128. Нашёл в просторах интернета следующий шрифт:

https://github.com/Holger-Will/code-128-font

Очень полезно было бы использовать данный шрифт при формировании штрихкода, но в отличии от того же Code 39, где каждый символ имеет свой рисунок штрихкода, здесь совершенно иной подход, с формированием стартовой точки, контрольных чисел и так далее...

Возможно ли создать такой метод, который формирует строку для данного шрифта из исходной строки данных в этом штрихкоде?

Comment: а готовые модули для code128 использовать не вариант?

Comment: @strawdog готовые модули, изученные мной в сети, генерируют картинки и svg'шки, с ними немного тяжелее работать, допустим, если захочется вставить такой в свой excel документ, то нужно поплясать с размерами

Comment: То есть, вы считаете, что если в  вашем документе будут символы с какими-то нестандартными шрифтами, то будет лучше?

Comment: @strawdog да, я считаю, что так будет лучше

Comment: @strawdog даже если потребуются картинки, можно же напрямую из того же шрифта и сгенерировать, предлагая чуть больше функционала по изменению, чем предлагают это другие библиотеки

Comment: @strawdog сверху можно добавить то, что хранить такие строки гораздо проще, чем если бы хотелось хранить штрихкод, или хранить данные из штрихкода, пихая везде где только можно энкодеры для рендера штрихкода